# An inequality to find the range of an unknown coefficient

Tags: inequality

Find the range of $a$ such that 
$$a(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)+2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+2x_1x_3 \geq 0, x_i\in \mathbb{R}$$
I tried to use Cauchy Inequality but it seems not...

Comment: Yes, I forgot it... But I want to ask if there is any difference for $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: In $\mathbb C$ the inequality will not be defined for most values (unless the terms somehow work out to be real).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: $a \ge 1$

Let $a=1:$ $$x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+2x_1x_3 =(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2\ge 0$$

If $a>1$ then $$(a-1)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+2x_1x_3 \ge 0$$

If $a<1, a=1- E$ then 
$(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2-E(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2)<0$ at $x_1=-x_2-x_3$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $a \ge 1$, we have $\forall x_i \in \mathbb R$,
$$LHS = (a-1)(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2) + (x_1+x_2+x_3)^2 \ge 0$$

This also indicates if $a< 1$, then when $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$, LHS is negative, so the range is $a \in [1, \infty)$.

Comment: I Got that !!! Thank you ><

Comment: But how about $a=1$, $(x_1+x_2+x_3)^2 \geq 0$ ?

Comment: It should be $+$ in the square ?